# Удаление элементов списка строк, индексами которого являются значения элементов другого списка

Tags: python

Есть лог-файл большого объема text.log, в нем необходимо найти строки, которые содержат записи, попадающие под регулярку, затем эти строки из списка text удалить, значения элементов списка `ip_list_numbers` как раз и будут индексами списка `text`.

Как удалить элементы списка `text`, индексы которых являются значениями списка `ip_list_numbers`?

```py
import re

f = open('text.log')
text = f.readlines()

ip_list_numbers = []
for line in text:
    i += 1
    result = re.search(r'\{\"ip\"\:\[\"(?P<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\"', str(text))
    if result:
       ip_list_numbers.append(i)

f.close()
```

Comment: Используйте `del text[index]`

Comment: Вместо `i += 1` можно использовать `for i, line in enumerate(text)`. Советом выше можно воспользоваться, но учтите, что удалять надо "с конца".

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления из списка используйте оператор `del` или метод `pop` (разница в том, что `pop` возвращает элемент), сам список строк нужно развернуть, чтобы удаление было с конца списка, т.к. уменьшение размера списка не актуализируется с текущим индексом и самое безобидное это приведет к выходу за пределы списка, а может удалить неправильный элемент.

Пример:

```
import re

with open('text.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

ip_list_numbers = []

for i, line in reversed(list(enumerate(lines))):
    result = re.search(r'\{\"ip\"\:\[\"(?P<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\"', line)
    if result:
        ip_list_numbers.append(i)
        lines.pop(i)
```

---

**PS.**

Вместо `enumerate`:

```
for i, line in reversed(list(enumerate(lines))):
    ...
```

можно использовать `range`:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(lines))):
    line = lines[i]
    ...
```